# Where the property "__proto_" is stored?

Tags: javascript

[image]

Tell me where the property "__proto_" is stored ?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto documentation ftw

Comment: Also: *"Furthermore, `__proto__` and the `__proto__` setter function are deprecated and should not be used."* -from above reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's inherited from `Object.prototype`:

```
({}).hasOwnProperty('__proto__') // false
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty('__proto__') // true
```

And according to [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto#Description),

> There is nothing special about the `__proto__` property.  It is simply
>   an accessor property -- a property consisting of a getter function and
>   a setter function -- on [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).  A property access for
>   "`__proto__`" that eventually consults [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) will find this
>   property, but an access that does not consult [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) will
>   not find it.  If some other "`__proto__`" property is found before
>   [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) is consulted, that property will hide the one found
>   on [Object.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Note this property isn't standard and some browsers may not have it. The standard way is:

- `Object.getPrototypeOf` to get the internal `[[Prototype]]`, defined in ES5.
- `Object.setPrototypeOf` to set the internal `[[Prototype]]`, defined in ES6.